# How to generate HTML on custom object using CDO with Oracle Eloqua

Tags: html, email, eloqua

We are using HTML in a Custom Object in Eloqua. We are importing this CDO to generate some emails.

The code can look like this:

`<ul> <li>Hello world</li><li>Hello Europe</li> </ul>`

On the mail the html is not display correctly. It's dsiplaying like string "

- Hello world
- Hello Europe

" and not like a html list.

We will like to know it's possible to generate HTML in Custom Object and call this object inside email.

Thank you for your help and have a nice day :)

Comment: Sounds like you have not specified the correct mime-type

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

How can i add the mime-type? Because i just have date, text, number etc... But no HTML in the type for my custom object.

Comment: I honestly have no idea at all about `Eloqua` - but if HTML is rendered as text in an email it suggests that the mimetype is wrong and the email headers are also incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious [character limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-user/Help/CustomObjects/CustomObjects.htm) in custom object fields (250 for standard text, 32,000 for large text), Eloqua is not designed to render the HTML from field merges, whether it comes from the contact record or the CDO.

What's the use case?